# Address on the Pin instead number in Google map in iphone

Tags: iphone

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a96118564f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a96118564f.png)

In above image, You can see the numbers on the pin.

I don't want that numbers,
Instead, when user clicks on that pin, Address of that location should be displayed?

I don't know how?
I have heard about customizing the pin.
I am trying.
But if you know, would you help me plz.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the context of the pin?  Is it an MKAnnotation in a MapKit map view?

Comment: Watch out my Answer. I have Solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `MKMapView`, then you need to create your own [`MKAnnotation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to add to the map.  The annotation class implement the following instance methods:

`- (NSString *)title`    - to return the title of the pin, which is usually the first line

`- (NSString *)subtitle`   - to return the subtitle of the pin, which is usually the second line.

Comment: I have already both methods as below.


-(NSString *)subtitle {
  
 return [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.latitude];
}

-(NSString *)title {
 
 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.longitude];
 
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) c {
 coordinate=c;
 NSLog(@"%f %f",c.latitude,c.longitude);
 return self;
}
What should i change??

Answer (score 4):

You've got two options here:

1. If all you want to do is take a latitude/longitude and present it as an address on the map, you'll need to use the `MKReverseGeocoder` class which will spit out a `MKPlacemark` that can then be added to your `MKMapView` using `addAnnotation:`.
2. If you've got some class of "thing" you'd like added to the map such as a "Person", you should make the class conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol (i.e. it needs a coordinate, title and subtitle property). You can then implement the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method on your `MKMapView` delegate and return a custom subclass of `MKAnnotationView`. This will get added to the map when your "Person" becomes visible in the map view.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot,
you made my day,
i was very surprised what it is happening when i found that
my subtitle is not taking nsstring stringwithformat,
it was crashing and it was taking it when i assigned direct same hardcoded value
in string format. very strange ,
now atleast it is not crashing
thanks a lot for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I got Something Different Solution. As per the instructions of @msaeed,
I have changed the constructor of my class. i have implemented following code & it works as what i required

```
-(NSString *)subtitle {
return [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.latitude];
}
-(NSString *)title {
return Title;
//  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.longitude]; 
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  
{
coordinate=c;
return self;

}

-(id)initWithCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) c Title:(NSString*)xz

{
coordinate=c;   
if(self=[super init])
{
    if(Title!=nil)
        [Title release];
    Title=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:xz];
}
return self;
```

}

watch out the following image, that i have solved.
[image solved. http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fae045c2bf.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fae045c2bf.png)